# Saving data to Database from HTML Input

Tags: php, html, mysql

It's been a long time since my last question. I have a HTML user interface with an input from a user and I would like to insert this input into database. It doesn't work and I don't know why... I have used a lot of hints from here, but still nothing.

```
<form action = ".\addProduct.php" method="post">
    <div id="AddProduct" class = "w3-container list w3-animate-left">
        <h2>Add Product</h2>
        ID: <br>
        <input type = "text" name = "ID"/><br>
        CName: <br>
        <input type = "text" name = "CName"/><br>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Add"/><br>
    </div>
</form>

<?php
// MY PHP CODE
if(isset($_REQUEST['Add'])) {
    $SQL = "USE sales;"
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO customers(ID, CName) values('" . $_POST["ID"] . "', '". $_POST["CName"] . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
?>
```

Comment: .\addProduct.php should be ./ and you need name=add on submit button

Comment: You're also assigning two different things to the same php variable.

Comment: and if you use method post so you should handle this method too, if(isset($_POST['add'])) {...

Comment: you also tagged as javascript but nothing to support the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mysqli instead of mysql.
Also sanitize the user input before you input them to the database.

```
<form action = "addProduct.php" method="post">
<div id="AddProduct" class = "w3-container list w3-animate-left">
    <h2>Add Product</h2>
        ID: <br>
        <input type = "text" name = "ID"/><br>
        CName: <br>
        <input type = "text" name = "cName"/><br>
        <br>
        <input type = "submit" name = "Add" value = "Add"/><br>
</div>
</form>



<?php
if(isset($_POST['Add']))
{
$cID = $_POST['ID'];
$cName = $_POST['cName'];

$SQL = "INSERT INTO customers(ID, CName) values('$cID', '$cName')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$SQL);
}
?>
```

Comment: here $conn is the connection to your database

Comment: Where is the sanitation of the user input you are speaking of? :D

Comment: If it is a spoon feeding answer, then I will post it. It is better to learn it instead of copying it from here! :D

Comment: This seems working - no error etc - but when I refresh the table in database nothing changes.
btw I'm trying to learn it, I'm just stucked on this one problem :)

Comment: @JiříChobotHamr The answer is incorrect for a few reasons and you should (eventually) be getting errors once that conditional statement fires up; you're just not looking for them. Plus, we don't know which MySQL API you are (now) using to connect with. `mysql_`? - `mysqli_`? PDO? Other?

Comment: @JiříChobotHamr if you are not using $result anywhere else to perform the query, just use mysqli_query($conn,$SQL); instead of assigning it to $result varaible. Also is your connection to the database successful?

Comment: @workthat *"If it is a spoon feeding answer, then I will post it."* - It's not a question of spoonfeeding, it's a matter of supplying them with proper syntax, which you haven't done. Edit: Ok, you fixed "one" thing, but not the other, being the conditional statement and nothing in there will fire up.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Good point! I'm using a WEBrick with mysql_. Btw is there any other way, how to do it, instead of using php?

Comment: @workthat `if(isset($_POST['Add']))` that will never fire up. There's no matching `name` attribute for it ;-) just `value = "Add"`

Comment: @workthat Oops `$_POST['cName']` and `name = "CName"` too. Those are case-sensitive too. Those should both match in letter-case. `cName` and `CName` are two different animals ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have already edited name = "Add" into my code, somebody mentioned it in one of first comments :)

Comment: @JiříChobotHamr Ok but my commenting is for future readers to the question/answer and should reflect the proper syntax. Not everyone knows that ;-) always check for errors with error reporting and MySQL error checking.

Comment: @Fred-ii- do you see any other errors? I should have taken time to make sure the syntax was correct haha.

Comment: @workthat Looks good from here ;-) However... I like to add error reporting/checking to answers and to also outline where the errors were made. The more the answer is informative, the more chances that the question/answer will be visited and in turn... well... more rep ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- gotchya! will keep that in mind from next time ;)

Comment: @workthat *ah, benissimo!!* It's not too late to edit your answer (if you wish). You can do that anytime too. ;-)

Comment: @JiříChobotHamr If you are connecting to your db using the `mysql_` API, you will need to switch over to `mysqli_` in order for the answer to work. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php to see how to connect using the MySQLi_ API and remember that you can't mix `mysql_` and `mysqli_` together. It's best to use MySQLi_, as the older one is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and has been removed from PHP 7.0